# Documentacion en Sphinx - No me genera la referencia a un html

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Instalé Sphinx con `pip install sphinx`
luego entre a la carpeta que quería trabajar la documentación con sphinx
ejecuté el comando `sphinx-quickstart` me procede hacer cuatro preguntas a lo que respondo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me crea los siguientes archivos **A Excepción de "Analisis.py, ventana.qml y ventanaqmlc" que son los codigos que deseo documentar**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cree un archivo llamado "prueba.rst"
e hice la refencia desde el index.rst al prueba.rst de la siguiente manera

index.rst:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego ejecuté desde el powershell el siguente comando `.\make html` y me generó los respectivos archivos .html incluyendo 'prueba.html' generado del prueba.rst.

El problema es que cuando abro el **index.html** me sale la lista de los nombres que estan colocados en el index.rst, sin embargo no puedo hacer el hipervinculo entre prueba a prueba.html.

Me explico mejor de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que trato de decir es que no se puede hiperivincular "prueba" con prueba.html.

Alguien sabrá que esta pasando? pongo el procedimiento completo porque quizá en algunos pasos de instalación o de comandos me habré equivocado.

Answer (score 0):

El archivo *prueba.rst* debe estar a la par del arhivo *index.rst* (no aparece en el screenshot que adjuntaste).

Otra cosa que puedes revisar es la configuración de:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("
```

en el archivo *conf.py* (deberías mostrar el contenido de este archivo también).

Sphinx trata diferente a imágenes o enlaces (externos o internos) que no puede encontrar.